# results not binding with stored procedure call MySQL php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedures, and i am having an issue with the results returned by the stored procedure not having any values when i call the stored procedure via PHP.  When i manually make the call directly on the MySQL server it works fine and returns 5 values.  When i call the procedure through php no values are stored in the binding variables.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE `TPE_GET_current_repair` (IN current_repair_vid VARCHAR(45))
    BEGIN
    SELECT current_repair_vid v1;

    SELECT 
        sys_vendor.vendor, 
        receive_date, 
        tape_repair_problem_code.tape_repair_problem_reason, 
        sys_tape_type.tape_type, 
        sys_capture_location.capture_location
    FROM tape_repair
        INNER JOIN `sys_vendor` on tape_repair.vendor_id = sys_vendor.id
        INNER JOIN `tape_repair_problem_code` on tape_repair.problem_code = tape_repair_problem_code.id
        INNER JOIN `sys_tape_type` on tape_repair.tape_type_id = sys_tape_type.id
        INNER JOIN `sys_capture_location` on tape_repair.capture_location_id = sys_capture_location.id
    WHERE vid = current_repair_vid;
    END
```

**PHP:**

```
    $repairData = "CALL TPE_GET_current_repair('$vid')";
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($repairData)) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($rpr_vendor, $rpr_rcv_date, $rpr_problem, $rpr_tape_type, $rpr_capt_loctn);
        $stmt->fetch();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, i had forgotten about the first select statement and it was causing the statement to fail.